# chrome extension -- appending div to body not working with facebook like button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension and I've been successful so far. As a last functionality I'm trying to attach a div (something that shows a small, non-irritating ad about my personal site) to the body of the currently opened tab/page when the user clicks the about section in my extension's panel. I got it working too.

But the problem is, this div is NOT getting attached to the body tag of the main page if that page contains facebook like or twitter follow widget. Instead it gets attached to the body tag in the iframe of the above said widgets.

When I checked the dom structure of such pages, these widgets create their own html>body structure within an iframe. And that's what causing this issue.

I tried attaching this div to the first body element as follows:

```
var mainbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
mainbody[0].appendChild(adDiv);  --> adDiv = new element I created above this code with its own properties
```

By the above 2nd statement I was expecting it to get attached to the first  tag and not onto the inner  tags.

Unfortunately this is not working either. I can see it getting attached to the facebook/twitter widget instead of the main . Is there anything wrong in what I'm doing?

---

**Edit**

From @stan's comment I was able to fix the issue in pages with facebook/twitter widget(ie the ones with iframes). Now my code looks like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(adDiv);
```

-- Thanks Stan.

But now I'm facing another issue. In certain sites (like http://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm) div is not appearing in the page. What actually happens is, the div is getting attached to the body but at the very same moment its getting removed also. It can be seen only with the help of html inspector(chrome's inspector in this case).

The div(adDiv) gets attached to the body in the markup and vanishes. **It's as if its unable to bind itself to the body**. Result: nothing appearing in the page.

Any idea why this is happening? Its happening only in a minority of sites like the above said one.

---

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{clicked:1});
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    if(request.clicked==1){
        /* Create adDiv and apply style to it using JS */
        document.body.appendChild(adDiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some example of site that is not working because I can't reproduce it. I've tried [this](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/10/30/hurricane-sandy-storm_n_2042815.html) and [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) but no luck. On every page only one `<body>` is found. I also tried waiting for page to load completely (so that I'm sure that all social widgets are loaded) but I'm still getting one `<body>` out of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')`.

Comment: You could possibly try `document.body.appendChild`?

Comment: @Stan that did the trick. Thanks! 
But in certain sites (like http://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm) I can see that the div gets attached and gets removed at same instant. I noticed this using chrome's html inspector. I can see the div getting attached to the body in the markup but at the same moment its deleted.  Result: nothing appearing in the page. Any idea why?

Comment: If this happens only on specific sites (and work on all the others), you should analyze their javascripts, I think. Perhaps, if you postpone your child appending to a moment when the site's scripts finished their job, you may succeed. If the scripts do monitor DOM changes, you should somehow block them from your extension, but this  will break the site's normal behaviour of course.

Comment: But don't our extension's JS code work in an entirely isolated environment? If so, how can I block or deal with site's JS?

Comment: (I didn't get notification because you didn't mention username ;-) I mean, you can choose from 2 approaches. First, monitor DOM on your own and restore/recreate the required div each time your notice it's missing (this could possibly lead to endless loop if site's script will do just the contrary). Second, you can intercept http-request using `webRequest` and deny appropriate scripts from loading. But this is not a general approach since it requires an apriory knowledge about specific site. Did you try postponed appending of the child?

Comment: @stan Sorry, forgot the username part! :) 1st method sounds risky and 2nd one is bit too hacky, right? My extension appends the div only when user invokes extension by icon click or via shortcut key. So there would be plenty of delay already right? (Assuming that user wont invoke extension without the page being fully loaded)

Comment: @stan If I were to postpone the appending action, how could I implement that? Put a simple sleep/delay just before the appending statement?

Comment: You did not mention how and at which moment your code appends the child (this can be important). Just for the testing you can postpone execution by `setTimeout`, right?

Comment: @Stan when the user invokes the extension it adds the div to the body.

Comment: What is the extension's panel? If it's a popup page, then you can't invoke the script from it directly in a tab, so you should use messaging, or call something in background page and then `executeScript`. Please, add a code excerpt to the question.

Comment: @Stan could you check now? I have added the code. I'm not using any other page. Just these 2 JS pages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18986/discussion-between-goose-and-stan)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you waiting for the DOM to be ready?  Cause if not, that could cause problems.

Comment: @LukeGT The extension is invoked on user's choice, ie when user clicks the extension icon. So waiting for the DOM to be ready or not actually depends on user's action.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1-st part of the question you should possibly try `document.body.appendChild`. [It turned out that it worked well.]

For the 2-nd part of the question, I made a test extension with your code (just added some stuff to define the div) and it works perfectly on the http://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm, that is I see the div in the bottom of the page after clicking on the action button. Please, make sure there is no any other extension intervening in your browser - disable all other extensions. Here is how I define the div (this may important as well):

```
var adDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
adDiv.id = "idadv"; 
adDiv.style.width = "200px"; 
adDiv.style.height = "100px"; 
adDiv.style.display = "block"; 
adDiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

As you said that the problem appears sporadically (and I'm unable to reproduce it either), I suppose it will be hard to intercept it. As a workaround you may try watching DOM and recreating the div every time it seems missing, something like that:

```
setInterval(createDivIfDoesNotExist, 1000);
```

Also you should possibly consider another placement for your self-ad, for example just show a popup which is bound to the browser action via manifest and don't alter external pages through browserAction's event listener.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix second issue with your patch. That issue happens only at random intervals on that page. The only thing that changes in that page are the Ad iframes. So I'm guessing its caused by those Ad widgets. Whats your thought on this random behaviour?

Comment: @goose, added some thoughts in the answer.